# upload a file in headless mode for robot framework

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, file-upload, robotframework

I'm writing an automated test in the robot framework and I need help to upload a file in headless mode for the below HTML code using robot framework libraries or some code in python or javascript or ajax.

```html
<div class="mx-name-fileManager1 mx-fileinput mx-filemanager form-group no-columns" style="width: 95%; padding-left: 40px;">
    <label class="control-label" for="110.ServiceAsset.UploadDocument_SparePart.fileManager1.11_bch_133" id="110.ServiceAsset.UploadDocument_SparePart.fileManager1.11_bch_133-label">Upload Document
    </label>
    <div class="mx-compound-control" data-focusindex="0">
        <form class="sr-only" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            <input type="file" tabindex="-1" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx,.ppt,.pptx,.odt">
        </form>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="" aria-labelledby="110.ServiceAsset.UploadDocument_SparePart.fileManager1.11_bch_133-label" value="...">
        <button type="button" class="btn mx-button mx-fileinput-upload-button" id="110.ServiceAsset.UploadDocument_SparePart.fileManager1.11_bch_133-upload" aria-labelledby="110.ServiceAsset.UploadDocument_SparePart.fileManager1.11_bch_133-label 110.ServiceAsset.UploadDocument_SparePart.fileManager1.11_bch_133-upload">Browse...
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use [Robot Framework Selenium library](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary), open browser and navigate to page where you need to upload. Then you can upload with this code snippet

```
Choose File    xpath://input[@type="file"]    ${CURDIR}/somefile.doc
```

Comment: Thank you. I was earlier using the input tag which is outside of the form tag, not the inside one. So I thought the 'Choose File' keyword won't work here. Thanks again

Comment: @T-2021 To identify that file upload input tag you should have checked the type attribute. The inside from input tag has `type=file` and the outside one has type as text